# Not able to focus on Entry inside nested ListView in Xamarin Forms

Tags: android, listview, xamarin, xamarin.forms, xamarin.android

I have a ListView with 2 control in ViewCell. 1- Entry, 2- Another ListView with Entries.

Now I am facing unique problem.

Case-1: If I tap on Entry inside nested ListView, I am not able to click. It behave like read only.

Case-2: If first I tap on Entry which is not inside nested ListView, I am able to focus on it. After this, I am also able to tap/focus on Entry which is inside the nested ListView.

It means I must tap on the Entry(without nested ListView) first, then I am able to tap or focus on Entry(with nested ListView).

I attached code here Kindly see code and send appropriate answer.

***MainPage.Xaml***

```
<ListView Grid.Row="1" HasUnevenRows="True" IsPullToRefreshEnabled="False"
    ItemsSource="{Binding MainListViewItemSource}" CachingStrategy="RecycleElement"
    ItemTapped="OnListViewItemTapped" ItemSelected="OnListViewItemSelected">
    <ListView.ItemTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
            <local:MyCell/>
        </DataTemplate>
    </ListView.ItemTemplate>
</ListView>
```

***MyCell.xaml***

```
<Image Source="{Binding PlusMinusImage}>
    <Image.GestureRecognizers>
        <TapGestureRecognizer Tapped="ListOpenCommand" NumberOfTapsRequired="1"/>
    </Image.GestureRecognizers>
</Image>
<StackLayout IsVisible={Binding IsVisible}>
    <Label Text="Mainlabel" FontSize="15" FontFamily="Roboto" TextColor="Black"/>
    <Entry x:Name="MainEntry" TextColor="Gray" Text="{Binding MainEntryValue}">
    <ListView ItemsSource="{Binding MyInnerListViewItemSource}" 
        ItemTapped="OnListViewItemTapped" ItemSelected="OnListViewItemSelected">
        <ListView.ItemTemplate>
            <DataTemplate>
                <ViewCell>
                    <Grid>
                        <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                            <ColumnDefinition Width="*"/>
                            <ColumnDefinition Width="*"/>
                        </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                        <Label Margin="0" Text="SampleInnerText" Grid.Column="0"/>
                        <Entry Margin="0" Text="{Binding SampleInnerTextValue}" 
                            Grid.Column="1"/>
                    </Grid>
                </ViewCell>
            </DataTemplate>
        </ListView.ItemTemplate>
    </ListView>
</StackLayout>
```

***MainPage.xaml.cs/MyCell.xaml.cs***

```
private void OnListViewItemSelected(object sender, SelectedItemChangedEventArgs e)
{
    (sender as ListView).SelectedItem = null;
    return;
}
private void OnListViewItemTapped(object sender, ItemTappedEventArgs e)
{
    if (e.Item == null) return;
    ((ListView)sender).SelectedItem = null;
}
```

***Android Listview Renderer***

```
protected override void OnElementPropertyChanged(object sender, PropertyChangedEventArgs e)
{
    base.OnElementPropertyChanged(sender, e);
    if (Control!=null)
    {
        Control.HorizontalScrollBarEnabled = false;
        Control.VerticalScrollBarEnabled = false;
        Control.Focusable = true;
        Control.FocusableInTouchMode = true;
    }

}
```

Comment: Share your code and just so you know never nest listviews into one another it is considered as a bad practice

Comment: @G.hakim I added code Can you please go through that and help me to solve that? Thanks

Comment: Can you give me a pictorial representation of what you are trying to do? Everything else seems to be okay

Comment: On image Tap stack panel visibility is set and after open it work like first Focus or select main ListView and than inner ListView as I mention above

Comment: Try using the RepeaterView instead of listview https://depblog.weblogs.us/2017/09/24/xamarin-forms-repeaterview/

Comment: Ohk Thanks for the help. Let me try.

Comment: Sure use repeaterView only for the inner Nested ListView and not for both

Comment: On selection it's color is change it looks weird and It works on `UWP` I am on doubt about that.

Comment: You can stop that easily that is not a problem it's your listviews selection property when you turn it off it will be fine

Comment: Then i do not know how to do it since I have never tried nested listviews

Comment: I am sorry but I can not use repeater view. Can you please suggest your thoughts sir. Thanks

Comment: I would suggest you add a non scrollable listview if you have to nest it like that

Comment: Ohk I try to achieve that and I do it using custom renderer and stop horizontal and vertical scroll in listview but till issue is facing in android.

Comment: Upload your android nonscroll listview code

Comment: Can you please check? I add my renderer code of android ListView that I mention in Question

Comment: I have added the code in an answer below to make it nonscrollable

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Following is the code for a non-scrollable listview take a look :

```
 public class NonScrollableListViewRenderer : ListViewRenderer
{
    public NonScrollableListViewRenderer(Context context) : base(context)
    {

    }
    protected override void OnElementChanged(ElementChangedEventArgs<Xamarin.Forms.ListView> e)
    {
        base.OnElementChanged(e);
        try
        {
            if (e == null || e.NewElement == null)
            {
                return;
            }
            var lit = e.NewElement;
            if (e.NewElement != null)
            {
                var listView = this.Control as Android.Widget.ListView;
                listView.NestedScrollingEnabled = true;
            }
        }
        catch (System.Exception ex)
        {
            AppLogger.LogException(ex);
        }
    }



    public Android.Views.View getViewByPosition(int pos, Android.Widget.ListView listView)
    {
        try
        {


            int firstListItemPosition = listView.FirstVisiblePosition;
            int lastListItemPosition = firstListItemPosition + listView.Adapter.Count - 1;

            if (pos < firstListItemPosition || pos > lastListItemPosition)
            {
                return listView.Adapter.GetView(pos, null, listView);
            }
            else
            {
                int childIndex = pos - firstListItemPosition;
                return listView.GetChildAt(childIndex);
            }
        }
        catch (System.Exception ex)
        {
            AppLogger.LogException(ex);
            return null;
        }
    }


    public override void OnViewAdded(Android.Views.View child)
    {
        base.OnViewAdded(child);

    }


    protected override void OnDetachedFromWindow()
    {
        try
        {
            if (Control == null)
            {

            }
            if (Element == null)
            {

            }
            base.OnDetachedFromWindow();

        }
        catch (System.Exception ex)
        {
            AppLogger.LogException(ex);
        }
    }


    protected override void Dispose(bool disposing)
    {
        disposing = false;
        if (Element == null)
        {

        }
        if (Control == null)
        {

        }
        base.Dispose(disposing);
    }
}
```

Comment: But scroll isn't issue for me My issue focus entry inside inner listview.

Comment: You are not able to focus it because of multiple scrolls this is a bad approach i already told you

Comment: Ohk Again thanks for the help. Let try to debug code that shared by you.

Comment: It looks same not solving my issue sorry for that. :(

Comment: Okay sorry could not help you in case i find anything related to this will get back to you

Comment: Hi Buddy Thanks for the help it works for me but When I try to focus entry it being focus but keyboard is not open lit like focus and remove focus in a fraction of second if there any missing. Please help

Comment: Force open the keyboard then

Comment: How to achieve that and in that I have to code in renderer or in .xaml.cs ?

Comment: Google how to force open keyboard in xamarin forms

Comment: Thanks for the help but again one issue arise and that is I gets last `Entry` and second major issue is if I am not able to click on above entry until main listview's entry is not being focused. Please suggest.!

Comment: And one more issue like error is that keyboard is open and focus is there but not able to edit value.

Comment: Hello! I am not able to produce reproduce RepeaterView inside the RepeaterView Can you please explain?

Comment: You don't use repeater inside repeater you use repeater inside list view

Comment: Thanks bro Finally done with that and happy with your answer. Thank you very much